# how to find and display files with similar file names using assembly language?

Tags: assembly

The machine problem is to find and display files with similar file names on different directories, using assembly language.. a console program compiled using tasm & tlink or emulator 8086 ...

Here's the code that I have tried, it only displays the list of files. My problem is i don't know how to make it display only those files with similar file names .. any ideas with regards to my problem will really be appreciated. Thanks ..

```
.model small, c

.stack

.data
    file_spec db "*.*", 0
    DTA db 128h dup(0)
    buffer db 30 dup(0)

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @Data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx,offset DTA
    mov ah,1Ah
    int 21h ; set DTA location

    mov dx,offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah,4Eh
    int 21h
    jc  quit

print_name:
    lea si, DTA + 30

next_char:
    lodsb
    int 29h
    test al, al
    jnz next_char

    mov al, 13
    int 29h
    mov al, 10
    int 29h

    mov dx, offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah, 4fh
    int 21h
    jnc print_name

quit:   
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
    end main
```

Here's another source code that i have tried, this time i have used int 21h , 4eh , 4fh (in MS Dos) .. please can someone help me enhance this code to be able to display only those files with similar file names? any kind of help will be so much appreciated. Thanks in advance..

```
.model small, c

.stack

.data
    file_spec db "*.*", 0
    DTA db 128h dup(0)

.code
    main proc
    mov ax, @Data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx,offset DTA
    mov ah,1Ah
    int 21h

    mov dx,offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah,4Eh
    int 21h
    jc  quit

print_name:
    lea si, DTA + 1eh
next_char:
    lodsb
    int 29h
    test al, al
    jnz next_char

    mov al, 13
    int 29h
    mov al, 10
    int 29h

    mov dx, offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah, 4fh
    int 21h
    jnc print_name
 quit:   
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
 main endp
    end main
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The post is missing question portion and sample code you have problem with... Otherwise it is not right place to hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: gcc -S... or just drop the course ;).  Filesystem interaction via assembly is painful. There is no reasonable justification for doing it - high-level languages exist for a reason.

Comment: You haven't even mentioned which operating system will be used. Assuming that it is DOS, you should take a look at the INT 21H list: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm    for example, AH=4EH (FindFirst) and AH=4FH (FindNext).

Comment: i would really be grateful to anyone who could help me with this machine problem ... i admit i don't have strong foundation in assembly language programming that's why i am having a hard time implementing this MP. I do hope someone could help me with this ... Thanks an God bless!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a tough project, asmaj! You've got a good start with listing file names. When you say "similar file names", I ASSume you mean "identical file names in different directories". (else you need to define "similar"). You've listed files in one directory. To switch to a different directory, you probably need to set a different DTA and start over again with "find first". When "find next" finally fails, you'll want to "set DTA" back to your previous DTA ("find next" depends on it) and continue with that directory. The "neat" way to do this is with a recursive function (calls itself) with a "local variable" (on the stack) for each DTA. Then when you `ret` from subsequent calls, you'll have the "right" DTA back.

I have an example of this - in Nasm syntax (not what you're using!). It just lists "all files in all directories", doesn't attempt to check for duplicates. I had a copy of this linked on my home page, but it's dead - uppity ISP has apparently removed it. I think I can find it, and I can mail it to ya - fbkotler (pig's tail) myfairpoint (decimal point) net - it's in the "wrong" syntax, and doesn't do all that you want, but "might" be some help...

Seems to me that to find duplicate file names, you're going to need to compare each file name found, to each and every file found on all other subdirectories. The "string" instruction `rep cmpsb` will probably be useful to do the comparison, but it's a bear of a job! Just finding "myfile.asm", "myfile.obj" and "myfile.exe" (maybe ".lst" and ".map" too) in a single directory would be easier, if that'll satisfy the "customer"...

I don't envy you, but hope to hear more from you on the subject...

Comment: Yes i am referring to identical file names in different directories ... i understand your point and i sincerely appreciated your ideas. I know I'm not really good in assembly language programming but I will try my best to apply your ideas ... if you can find the example that you mentioned above, i would be grateful to you if you can send it on my e-mail (khalidjamerah@ymail.com), perhaps it would be helpful to me .. thank you so much!

Comment: i really have to finish this machine problem asap ... Frank ,thanks for giving some of your time ... please if you have time can you send the example you've mentioned above right away? perhaps it would really be helpful ... thanks and god bless!